# How to get list of permissions of a folder/file with Google Drive API php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I just want to ask how to get the list of permission users in Google Drive API with PHP?

I tried :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('gdrive/json/'. $_SESSION['json'] . '.json');
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setSubject($_SESSION['json_email']);
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($GLOBALS['client']);
                        
        $idfolder = "1OkkVahAzWkmHlRI9AzuH8uSSK";
        $results = $service->files->get($idfolder);
        $permissions = $results->getpermissions();  
            

foreach( $permissions as $kk => $users) {
            
            echo $users['displayName']  ;       
            echo $users['type'] ;       
            echo $users['emailAddress'] ;       
    }
```

But it doesn't showing anything but when I echo $permissions variable it is displaying "Array"

Can someone please help. Thank you!

Comment: Is PHP error reporting turned on? The method does not appear to be cased correctly, it should be `getPermissions()` as far as I can tell. Have you tried running `var_dump` on the results of that call?

Comment: @ChrisHaas No sir I haven't tried running var_dump. May I know how?

Comment: I also tried getPermissions() but still when I echo @permissions. It is display same result "Array" but when I insert in foreach loop it still displaying empty.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: When you say it doesn’t show anything, that leads me to believe there’s an error, please turn on error reporting

Comment: Yes sir as per checking var dump is turn on but it really shows empty. You may see here the web result above and the code below https://imgur.com/gallery/xRliPpz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235036/discussion-between-mon-padi-and-chris-haas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

In many API methods, the server doesn't return all resource fields but just a default subset of it. In order to retrieve non-default fields, you have to set the parameter `fields`.

In this case, you are not setting `fields` in your request, so the response doesn't contain the file `permissions`.

#### Solution:

Set the `fields` property in order to return the file `permissions` (`*` is a special value that can be used to return all fields):

```
$idfolder = "YOUR_FILE_ID";
$optParams = array(
  'fields' => '*'
);
$results = $service->files->get($idfolder, $optParams);
$permissions = $results->getPermissions();
```

#### Note:

Consider calling [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) instead of [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get), if you just want to retrieve the `File` permissions:

```
$results = $service->permissions->listPermissions($idfolder, $optParams);
```

#### Reference:

- [Return specific fields for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter)
- [Class Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource: get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource.html#_get)

Comment: Thank you sir! This is exactly what I am looking for.